# Create IOS Control Center type Drawer

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uiviewanimation

I need to implement the IOS Control Center style drawer where user
1. Can slide up and down the custom view.
2. If user tries to slide up beyond the desired height, it should stretch to a limit and then come back to its previous state. The same way it is happening in the iOS Control Center.
3. When user slide down a bit it should close and vice versa.
4. Opening the custom view the way Control Center opens with spring animation.

Could anyone guide me as how it can be achieved?